# Why this bit manipulation program is giving wrong O/P?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

```
/* This program's aim is to count the number of bits set in an integer */

#include<stdio.h>

int count=0;
int check(int);

int main()
{
int i,r;
char ch;
printf("enter the integer for which you want to check the bits set");
scanf("%d", &i);
r=check(i);
printf("the number of occurance of 1 in the integer is  %d \n", r); /*don't know why isit         printing 0 when i give 4 as input */
    return 0;
}


int check(int j)
{

if((j & 1)==1)
count++;

for(int l=0;l<31;l++)
{

    if( j>>1 & 1)
    count++;

}
return count;

}
```

What is wrong with this program?  Looks like some silly mistake or some conceptual one.
Also do we need to write j>>1? can't we simply write j>>?

Comment: You should really improve your code formatting.

Comment: please fix the indentation and add a language tag

Comment: For other implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/109023

Answer (score 0):

`j >> 1` is wrong, so asking why you need to write that doesn't make much sense.

`j >>` makes even less sense. You don't write `j +` or `j *`  either, do you? So why should that work for `>>`?

Anyway, you could test every bit by shifting by `l` (that's a lower case L, not a one), or you could change `j` so it only has to be shifted by 1 at every step. Here's a relatively minimal change to your code that does it the second way, I also changed the global `count` to a local because it was really poor form.

```
int check(int j)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < 32; l++)
    {
        if (j & 1)
            count++;
        j >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

There are still issues with it.

What if `int` is not 32 bits? What about the 32nd bit? (ok you can write `l < 32` and maybe that's more in line with your code, I'm not sure what you really intended there)

Why is it even signed to begin with?

And `check` doesn't say much about what this function actually does, you could name this function `popcnt` or `hammingweight` or `numberOfSetBits` or something like that. And personally I'd use a different algorithm, but that's up to you.

Comment: i am taking the integer to be 32 bit. To chec the once place I have used the first check on count and for the remaining 31 places I have used the loop. Is there any other flaw you see?

Comment: @user3287223 if you change the type to `uint32_t` and change the name, it's OK IMO. By the way if you're learning about bits and want some help in understanding it, you can drop by in #omnimaga on efnet if you want. (or ask more questions on stackoverflow, of course)